# How to add a state into a api fetch()

Tags: json, reactjs, api, react-native

Hi I need to add a state into my API fetch but struggling to see why it works when the state is an empty string but does not work if there is a string inside the state please view the examples

The idea is the user enters new text in an input which updates the state Search and then updates fetch url so they can search the database

[image: Unhnadled Promise Rejection]

Example Working Code (Notice the state Search is empty)

```
export default class ThirdScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: '',
    image: ''
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchsa();
  }

  fetchsa = () => {
    const {search} = this.state;

    fetch(`https://xxx/search?q=moon&media_type=image`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => this.setState({
      image: result.collection.items[0].links[0].href
    }))

  }
```

Example not working Code

```
export default class ThirdScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: 'moon', //Notice this is not empty and now causes an error
    image: ''
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchsa();
  }

  fetchsa = () => {
    const {search} = this.state;

    fetch(`https://xxx/search?q='${search}'&media_type=image`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => this.setState({
      image: result.collection.items[0].links[0].href
    }))

  }
```

Comment: Your error is on the `result.collection.items[0].links` this kind of deconstruction is very error prone. Are you sure that the response from the api has the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem are the single quotes in your `fetch` URL**:

```
const search = 'moon';
fetch(`https://xxx/search?q='${search}'&media_type=image`)
```

is NOT the same as

```
fetch(`https://xxx/search?q=moon&media_type=image`)
```

The  API request goes through for `'moon'` instead of `moon` and no results are found.

However this is ok:

```
fetch(`https://xxx/search?q=${search}&media_type=image`)
```

So:

1. **Lose the single quotes around `${search}`.**
2. **Handle an empty `items` array when no results are found.**

For example:

```
fetch(`https://xxx/search?q=${search}&media_type=image`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => result.collection.items.length > 0 && this.setState({
        image: result.collection.items[0].links[0].href
    }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export default class ThirdScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: 'moon', //Notice this is not empty and now causes an error
    image: ''
  }


 componentDidMount() {
   this.fetchsa();
 }

 fetchsa = () => {
 const {search} = this.state;

 fetch(`https://xxx/search?q='${search}'&media_type=image`)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((result) => this.setState({
  result.collection && result.collection.items[0] && result.collection.items[0].links[0] ?image: result.collection.items[0].links[0].href:null
}))

}
```